# wkhtmltopdf anchor text having HTML. issue

Tags: html, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, tuespechkin, phpwkhtmltopdf

wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3.2 (with patched qt) -- Windows 8

If I include some html inside anchor tag then the generated pdf doesn't make it clickable.

**e.g** `<a href="#BarChart"><div><span>TreeMap!</span></div></a>`

**Command :** wkhtmltopdf.exe --enable-internal-links D:\A.html D:\test.pdf

Can anyone help me in this regard ?

----------------------- HTML -----------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
  .break{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#BarChart"><div><span>TreeMap!</span></div></a>
<div class="break"></div>
<a name="BarChart">nbsp</a>
<a href="#TextChart">Bar Chart!</a>
<div class="break"></div>
<a name="TextChart">nbsp</a>
<a href="#PieChart">Text Chart !</a>
<div class="break"></div>
<a name="PieChart">PieChart</a>
</body>
</html>
```

------------------------END-------------------------